# How do I scale default app size smaller than "Default" in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, scaling, high-dpi

I'm on a 1920x1080 pixel, 15.1" laptop running Windows 8.1. Some of my apps (Eclipse, SourceTree, pgAdmin, Chrome) render larger than I would like, fitting far less content than on Windows 7.

I can "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" for pgAdmin and Chrome, which allows me to fit much more content on the screen. However, this does not work for other apps (Eclipse, SourceTree).

The Windows Display Settings options allow me to "Change the size of apps, text, and other items on the screen (only applies to displays that can support it)." The only options are:

- Default
- Larger

"Default" is still way too large, rendering size 10 fonts nearly double the size of size 10 fonts in apps where display scaling is successfully disabled. The apps do not allow font size and button size adjustment low enough to fit as much content on the screen as if run under Windows 7.

Is there a way to scale smaller than "Default" on my display? I want to make use of my screen real-estate!!