# How to set the Metro app font size to "larger" when not offered?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, high-dpi

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro, which has a very high resolution display (3200x1800). In desktop mode, this is quite nice, since it gives me really sharp fonts (with the appropriate DPI setting). However, in "Modern"/Metro apps, I find the font size of most text to be a bit too small.

There is a setting called "Change size of apps text and others" at "Settings/PC and Devices/Screen"*, however the only options available are "Standard" and "Smaller". I know that other people have the option "Larger" ([this person has the opposite problem](https://superuser.com/questions/781552/how-do-i-scale-default-app-size-smaller-than-default-in-windows-8-1)). How can I set this to the larger setting?

Is it known what factors make the different setting available? For example, on some very low-resolution screens, the "smaller" setting is hidden. I can imagine reported physical screen size plays a role, too.

I know I can change the font sizes in individual apps sometimes, but I want to change this setting since it affects text everywhere. If there is no official trick, a registry hack or even a file patch would be OK.